# Query Money/BigDecimal Datatype

Tags: jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0, eclipselink

I am trying to query a table for finding a MRP price.

```
BigDecimal mrp = 5.5;

Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.mrp=:mrp");
query.set("mrp",mrp);
```

in the above i get a error

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: money = numeric
```

in normal sql syntax i would be using

```
select * FROM a.product WHERE mrp='5.5';
```

So now my question is how do i frame the search for a Money DataType in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Postgres wants you to bind a specific money type, instead of a BigDecimal.  You may need to map to the Postgres JDBC money type, or use a Converter in EclipseLink.

You could also disable parameter binding in the query so it prints the type as a String.

```
query.setHint("eclipselink.jdbc.bind-parameters", "false");
```